# Window sessionStorage Delay

Tags: javascript

I have a banner with a button; when I click the button, the banner disappears until the end of the session, and it reappears in a new session. The problem is that after clicking "Ok," the banner disappears correctly, but if I navigate between pages on the site, for a fraction of a second, I see it and then it disappears quickly. Is there a way to speed up the operation and prevent the banner from briefly appearing on each page change? Thank you

The code is:

```
<div id="cookie-banner">
    <p class="banner-text">Questo blog utilizza solo cookie tecnici necessari al suo funzionamento.</p>
    <button id="ok-button">OK</button>
</div>

<style>
    #cookie-banner {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    .banner-text {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #ok-button {
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        #cookie-banner {
            font-size: 21px;
            padding-left: 33px;
        }

        #ok-button {
            padding: 8px 16px;
            font-size: 30px;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    }
</style>

<script>
    // Funzione per chiudere il banner e impostare sessionStorage
    function chiudiBanner() {
        var banner = document.getElementById('cookie-banner');
        banner.style.display = 'none'; // Nasconde il banner
        sessionStorage.setItem('cookieConsent', 'true'); // Imposta sessionStorage per indicare il consenso durante la sessione
    }

    // Controlla se l'utente ha già fornito il consenso ai cookie
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var cookieConsent = sessionStorage.getItem('cookieConsent');
        if (cookieConsent === 'true') {
            var banner = document.getElementById('cookie-banner');
            banner.style.display = 'none'; // Nasconde il banner se l'utente ha già fornito il consenso durante questa sessione
        }
    });

    // Aggiungi un event listener al pulsante OK per chiudere il banner
    document.getElementById('ok-button').addEventListener('click', chiudiBanner);
</script>
```

I try this but not solve:

```
    <div id="cookie-banner" class="hidden">
    <p class="banner-text">Questo blog utilizza solo cookie tecnici necessari al suo funzionamento.</p>
    <button id="ok-button">OK</button>
</div>

<style>
    #cookie-banner {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    .banner-text {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #ok-button {
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        #cookie-banner {
            font-size: 21px;
            padding-left: 33px;
        }

        #ok-button {
            padding: 8px 16px;
            font-size: 30px;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    }
    
    .hidden {
    display: none;
}

</style>

<script>
    // Funzione per chiudere il banner e impostare sessionStorage
function chiudiBanner() {
    var banner = document.getElementById('cookie-banner');
    banner.classList.toggle('hidden'); // Toggles the "hidden" class
    sessionStorage.setItem('cookieConsent', 'true');
}


    // Controlla se l'utente ha già fornito il consenso ai cookie
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var cookieConsent = sessionStorage.getItem('cookieConsent');
        if (cookieConsent === 'true') {
            var banner = document.getElementById('cookie-banner');
            banner.style.display = 'none'; // Nasconde il banner se l'utente ha già fornito il consenso durante questa sessione
        }
    });

    // Aggiungi un event listener al pulsante OK per chiudere il banner
    document.getElementById('ok-button').addEventListener('click', chiudiBanner);
</script>
```

Comment: consider inverting your logic - add the banner only if you need to - hide it by default then show it

Comment: Isn't he already doing it now?

Comment: no, you have the opposite - you are hiding it using javascript, instead of showing it with javascript

Comment: but it has to show it at every new visit to the site, so how should it show it if not like this?

Comment: I can't store a permanent cookie, the cookie must die at the end of the session

Comment: use this as your logic `banner.style.display = 'block';` and work how to make that work

Comment: But better yet, don't set `style` directly, use a class called `hidden` that sets `display: none`, set the banner's class attribute to what it needs to be on initial page load in your HTML and then toggle your element's visibility by either adding/removing or toggling that class using the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property. Keep the actual CSS itself in your CSS files.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't solve, look at the question's edit, I posted the code.